# What if I do not want to sync contacts?

Tags: android, contacts, synchronization

In an Android app I'm working on, I'm using the `AccountManager` to store the user's account info and also sync a couple of sources (I have two services that respond to the `android.content.SyncAdapter` intent action).

However, I am not syncing contacts. In spite of this, if I go in the contacts app and choose to add a contact, I get a popup asking me under which account should the contact be created. The account created by my app is listed there as well. I have tried putting `android:supportsUploading="false"` on my `<sync-adapter>`s, doesn't work.

The only solution I currently see is to create an empty, invisible contact sync service that has `android:supportsUploading="false"`, but that seems like the biggest and most useless hack ever.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you have to specify both `android:supportsUploading="false"` AND your content authority must be `android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"` (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY).

See `com.android.contacts.model.Sources.queryAccounts()`, which fills in the .readOnly flag, and `com.android.contacts.model.Sources.getAccounts()`, which is used by `com.android.contacts.util.AccountSelectionUtil.getSelectAccountDialog()` to populate the contacts dialog.

What's not clear to me is whether this has additional (potentially undesirable) side effects -- particularly given that you're specifying a contentAuthority that is conceptually the opposite of what you want.

-Tim

Comment: Yup, that's what I ultimately did. It seems like a huge overlook on the Android team's part to assume that any app providing an account also syncs contacts.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to sync contacts change the authority of your syncadapter's xml file to the authority of your apps contact provider . If you are not maintaining a contacts provider for your app. Just make a dummy provider and gives its authority to your sync adapter's xml file. Giving authority as `com.android.contacts` in your syncadapter's xml file will cause this behavior as you mentioned :

"However, I am not syncing contacts. In spite of this, if I go in the contacts app and choose to add a contact, I get a popup asking me under which account should the contact be created. The account created by my app is listed there as well. I have tried putting `android:supportsUploading="false"` on my s, doesn't work."

doing this will solve this issue